# Does deleting an automatically generated label on a report add to the number of fields used on that report?

Tags: ms-access, report, label

I have created a report in designer view using MS Access 2013 on which, when I attempt to switch to Report View, I get the error *Too many fields defined.*  There are quite a few fields and controls on the report, but not 255, and so I am trying to recreate the report to see if the problem was in my changing and deleting fields and controls along the way.  However, in my new report, every time I add a field, a label is automatically also added, which I then need to delete.

Does deleting this automatically generated label add to the number of fields defined and, if so, is there a way to stop the program from automatically generating the label?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that deleted labels count for the limit (not sure if labels count at all).

Although this article: [Tables: "Too many fields defined" error message](http://access.mvps.org/access/tables/tbl0002.htm) indicates that deleted fields do count for tables.

The problem may also be in your datasource, if it contains many expressions/calculations, see here: http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Fields-Defined-t1924641.html

---

Anyway, to add e.g. new textboxes without labels:

- Select a textbox **without** label
- In Design - Controls, click **Set Control Defaults**

Alternatively, with the properties sheet open, click the "Add Textbox" button in the ribbon (the property sheet changes to "Default Textbox"), and set the `AutoLabel` property to No.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize you could set the properties for default controls.  I have read a couple of articles (which I can't seem to locate at the moment) that made it seem like any deleted control, as well as any changes made to the value within the control, adds to the field limit.  My datasource is a query that pulls from 10 tables and includes several expressions, but when I run the query it seems to work fine.  Thanks again for the help - I will see if creating the report again helps at all.